# Why can't I Access a Service Exposed from Minikube on Windows?

Tags: windows, kubernetes, service, minikube

I'm new to Kubernetes. I successfully created a deployment with 2 replicas of my Angular frontend application, but when I expose it with a service and try to access the service with 'minikube service service-name', the browser can't show me the application.

This is my docker file

```
FROM registry.gitlab.informatica.aci.it/ccsc/images/nodejs/10_15

LABEL maintainer="d.vaccaro@informatica.aci.it" name="assistenza-fo" version="v1.0.0" license=""

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ARG PRODUCTION_MODE="false"

ENV NODE_ENV='development'
ENV HTTP_PORT=4200

COPY package*.json ./

RUN if [ "${PRODUCTION_MODE}" = "true" ] || [ "${PRODUCTION_MODE}" = "1" ]; then \
    echo "Build di produzione"; \
    npm ci --production ; \
    else \
    echo "Build di sviluppo"; \
    npm ci ; \
fi

RUN npm audit fix

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli

COPY dockerize /usr/local/bin

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dockerize

COPY . .

EXPOSE 4200

CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

pod description

```
Name:           assistenza-fo-674f85c547-bzf8g
Namespace:      default
Priority:       0
Node:           minikube/172.17.0.2
Start Time:     Sun, 19 Apr 2020 12:41:06 +0200
Labels:         pod-template-hash=674f85c547
                run=assistenza-fo
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Running
IP:             172.18.0.6
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/assistenza-fo-674f85c547
Containers:
  assistenza-fo:
    Container ID:   docker://ef2bfb66d22dea56b2dc0e49e875376bf1edff369274015445806451582703a0
    Image:          registry.gitlab.informatica.aci.it/apra/sta-r/assistenza/assistenza-fo:latest
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://registry.gitlab.informatica.aci.it/apra/sta-r/assistenza/assistenza-fo@sha256:8d02a3e69d6798c1ac88815ef785e05aba6e394eb21f806bbc25fb761cca5a98
    Port:           4200/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Sun, 19 Apr 2020 12:41:08 +0200
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-zdrwg (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-zdrwg:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-zdrwg
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:          <none>
```

my deployment description

```
Name:                   assistenza-fo
Namespace:              default
CreationTimestamp:      Sun, 19 Apr 2020 12:41:06 +0200
Labels:                 run=assistenza-fo
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1
Selector:               run=assistenza-fo
Replicas:               2 desired | 2 updated | 2 total | 2 available | 0 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:  run=assistenza-fo
  Containers:
   assistenza-fo:
    Image:        registry.gitlab.informatica.aci.it/apra/sta-r/assistenza/assistenza-fo:latest
    Port:         4200/TCP
    Host Port:    0/TCP
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Available      True    MinimumReplicasAvailable
  Progressing    True    NewReplicaSetAvailable
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   assistenza-fo-674f85c547 (2/2 replicas created)
Events:          <none>
```

and my service description

```
Name:                     assistenza-fo
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   run=assistenza-fo
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 run=assistenza-fo
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.97.3.206
Port:                     <unset>  4200/TCP
TargetPort:               4200/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30375/TCP
Endpoints:                172.18.0.6:4200,172.18.0.7:4200
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

When i run the command

```
minikube service assistenza-fo
```

I get the following output:

```
|-----------|---------------|-------------|-------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |     NAME      | TARGET PORT |           URL           |
|-----------|---------------|-------------|-------------------------|
| default   | assistenza-fo |        4200 | http://172.17.0.2:30375 |
|-----------|---------------|-------------|-------------------------|
* Opening service default/assistenza-fo in default browser...
```

but Chrome prints out: "unable to reach the site" for timeout.

Thank you

**EDIT**

I create again the service, this time as a NodePort service. Still not working. This is the service description:

```
Name:                     assistenza-fo
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   run=assistenza-fo
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 run=assistenza-fo
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.107.46.43
Port:                     <unset>  4200/TCP
TargetPort:               4200/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30649/TCP
Endpoints:                172.18.0.7:4200,172.18.0.8:4200
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Comment: kubectl run assistenza-fo —image=“image address on registry” —port=4200 —replicas=2

Comment: Actually, the instruction `EXPOSE 4200` that you're using is just for documentation purpose. It doesn't really _exposes_ the port. So you need to expose it using `kubectl expose` command as shown [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/#create-a-service).

Comment: Also note that the example given in the link i mentioned is just to give an idea. That example is for exposing the service _outside_ of your cluster which may not be your case.

Comment: I just deleted my service and re-created it with this instruction:   "kubectl expose deployment assistenza-fo --type=LoadBalancer --port=4200"  but the result is the same. Actually I don't have any particular use case at the moment, I'm just trying to learn :) but I can't figure out the reason I cannot reach the pods. Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: Can you just try the following and then run the `minikube service assistenza-fo` command? `kubectl expose deployment assistenza-fo --type=NodePort --port=4200`

Comment: I get the same result(browser timeout) . Another thing: if i run the container from docker everything works fine and the container is reachable with localhost and with my ip at port 4200.

Comment: Actually, i haven't used Minikube so i was also just suggesting based on my experience with Docker. :( Hopefully, someone else will help you out.

Comment: I'd suggest verifying the app in the pods/containers is actually up and able to serve requests. Assuming the app writes logs to stdout, `kubectl logs <pod-name>` will print them; check them for errors. Get "iniside" the app container - `kubectl exec -it <pod-name> /bin/bash` (or whichever shell may be available) - and "poke around". e.g. use something like `curl` (if it is available) to submit requests to `localhost:4200`.

Comment: I can provide you a fully reproducible example for exposing on minikube, in the mean time can you attest the dockerimage, as in the example, works outside kubernetes?

Comment: @gears. I have checked the logs of the pods. The status is running, and the logs are clean. These are the last 2 lines of one pod: chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 5.19 MB [initial] [rendered]
[34mℹ[39m [90m｢wdm｣[39m: Compiled successfully.

Comment: @willrof: I have run my container from docker without problems, moreover i also tryed to expose the image used in the kubernetes basics tutorial: 'gcr.io/google-samples/kubernetes-bootcamp:v1'. I always get the browser timeout. Maybe I make some mistake I do not understand. The example would be really nice. Thank you

Comment: @Yanosh good, I will write you an example that you can reproduce using your image. And hopefully clear your doubts

Comment: @Yanosh quick question: are you able to `CURL http://172.17.0.2:30375` from your host machine?

Comment: I’m on windows. I can curl google.com but not the address of the service at the NodePort exposed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212168/discussion-between-willrof-and-yanosh).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue.

It's actually a bug on latest version of Minikube for Windows running Docker Driver: `--driver=docker`

- You can see it here: [Issue - minikube service not working with Docker driver on Windows 10 Pro #7644](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7644)
- it was patched with the merge: [Pull - docker driver: Add Service & Tunnel features to windows](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/pull/7739)
- it is available now on [Minikube v1.10.0-beta.0](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/tag/v1.10.0-beta.0)

In order to make it work, download the beta version from the website:

- https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/download/v1.10.0-beta.0/minikube-windows-amd64.exe
- move it to your working folder and rename it to `minikube.exe`

```
C:\Kubernetes>rename minikube-windows-amd64.exe minikube.exe

C:\Kubernetes>dir
22/04/2020  21:10    <DIR>          .
22/04/2020  21:10    <DIR>          ..
22/04/2020  21:04        55.480.832 minikube.exe
22/04/2020  20:05               489 nginx.yaml
               2 File(s)     55.481.321 bytes
```

- If you haven't yet, `stop` and `uninstall` the older version, then start Minikube with the new binary:

```
C:\Kubernetes>minikube.exe start --driver=docker
* minikube v1.10.0-beta.0 on Microsoft Windows 10 Pro 10.0.18363 Build 18363
* Using the docker driver based on existing profile
* Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
* Pulling base image ...
* Restarting existing docker container for "minikube" ...
* Preparing Kubernetes v1.18.0 on Docker 19.03.2 ...
  - kubeadm.pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
* Enabled addons: dashboard, default-storageclass, storage-provisioner
* Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube"

C:\Kubernetes>kubectl get all
NAME                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/nginx-76df748b9-t6q59   1/1     Running   1          78m

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP        85m
service/nginx-svc    NodePort    10.100.212.15   <none>        80:31027/TCP   78m

NAME                    READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/nginx   1/1     1            1           78m

NAME                              DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/nginx-76df748b9   1         1         1       78m
```

- Minikube is now running on version v1.10.0-beta.0, now you can run the service as intended (and note the command will be unavailable because it will be tunneling the connection:

[image]

- The browser will open automatically and your service will be available:

[image]

If you have any doubts let me know in the comments.

Comment: Thank you willrof! I can now view my application on the browser. The only thing I don't understand is: the node port of my service is the following: 'NodePort:  31378/TCP'. but when the browser start it points the following URL: http://127.0.0.1:55542/. My understand was it should be http://127.0.0.1:31378. I think this is related with the tunneling performed by minikube... right?

Comment: Docker Desktop for Windows (the driver we are using) [can’t route traffic to Linux containers.](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#i-cannot-ping-my-containers) this is why Minikube creates a tunnel to route the traffic and selects a different port. It's not pretty, but it's the current state. In order to have full connectivity you can use [hyperV Driver](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/hyperv/) if you run Windows 10 Pro/Enterprise/Education or the original [VirtualBox Driver](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/virtualbox/) for Windows 10 Home.